# java read JDBC connection from XML file

Tags: java, xml, jdbc

Anyone have idea how can i write XMl file that i will have JDBC connection (username, passwd, driver, connection) in it and then read that xml for connecting to db?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. Is it: a). How to structure the XML b). how to read the XML in Java c) how to use what you have parsed to make a JDBC connection? You should focus on one of those problems in this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you could compose the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <jdbc>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase</url>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <username>java</username>
        <password>d$7hF_r!9Y</password>
    </jdbc>
</config>
```

Assuming that it's called `config.xml` and is been placed in the root of the classpath, here's an example how you could load it with help of JAXP and [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(input));
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String url = (String) xpath.compile("//config//jdbc//url").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
String driver = (String) xpath.compile("//config//jdbc//driver").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
String username = (String) xpath.compile("//config//jdbc//username").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
String password = (String) xpath.compile("//config//jdbc//password").evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
// ...
```

It's only pretty verbose as opposed to properties files. Here's an example of such a properties file:

```
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase
jdbc.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.username = java
jdbc.password = d$7hF_r!9Y
```

Assuming that it's named `config.properties` and is been placed in the root of the classpath (or its root path is been added to the classpath), here's how you could load it from the classpath:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
String url = properties.getProperty("jdbc.url");
String driver = properties.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
String username = properties.getProperty("jdbc.username");
String password = properties.getProperty("jdbc.password");
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use the [Spring Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) to externalize the configuration of a connection pool and setup of the jdbc URL.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/). You can read multiple configuration formats with it.

That said, for database connection properties the a simple key-value `.properties` file is better, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own XML schema, bind it to a Java bean, and parse it through JAXB.
Then, you just have to invoke the getters of your bean to build your connection.