# Store config data into abstract class or interface

Tags: java, config

I work in a java library working with database. I want to store the config datas for use them to connection and sql queries.

How can store config data?
It's ok to put them into abstract final class?

```
public final class MySQLConfig {
    final public static String
        DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        DBURL  = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname",
        USER = "user",
        PASS = "pass",

        PREFIX = "vab_",

        CARDS_TABLE = "cards",
        CARDS_CARD_ID = "card_id",
        CARDS_OWNER_ID = "owner_id",
        CARDS_LABEL = "label",
        CARDS_AMOUNT = "amount",

        TRANSACTIONS_TABLE = "transactions",
        TRANSACTIONS_TRANSACTION_ID = "transaction_id",
        TRANSACTIONS_CARD_ID = "card_id",
        TRANSACTIONS_USER_ID = "owner_id",
        TRANSACTIONS_DESCRIPTION = "label",
        TRANSACTIONS_AMOUNT = "amount",
        TRANSACTIONS_DATE = "datetime",
        TRANSACTIONS_TYPE = "type",

    // Prevent create instance
    private MySQLConfig() {

    }
}
```

I use them like this:

```
public static Connection createConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(MySQLConfig.DRIVER);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(MySQLConfig.DBURL, MySQLConfig.USER, MySQLConfig.PASS);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Or in sql statement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + MySQLConfig.PREFIX + MySQLConfig.CARDS_TABLE + " ("
                    + MySQLConfig.CARDS_OWNER_ID + ", "
                    + MySQLConfig.CARDS_LABEL + ", "
                    + MySQLConfig.CARDS_AMOUNT + " "
                + ") "
                + "VALUES ("
                    + "'" + String.valueOf(ownerId) + "', "
                    + "'" + label + "', "
                    + "'" + initAmount.toPlainString() + "'"
                + ")";
```

How I can store correctly this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Config file for holding connection string parameters in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967558/config-file-for-holding-connection-string-parameters-in-java)

Comment: But I don't want to use a file for this purpose.

Comment: You failed to mention that requirement in your question, sorry.  Also, you realize that a java class is usually a file?  Any reason for not wanting to use a file?  You could supply a connection string on the command line and pull the rest of your configuration from that database